# If user adds "m" or "h" to input, print "mins" or "hours"

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, printing

I'm wanting to print "mins" if the user inputs a number with "m" after; and "hours" if user inputs number with "h" after.

My code:

```
import pyautogui
xtime = (input("Enter time (add: m for mins, or h for hrs): "))

if xtime + "m":
    print("mins")
elif xtime + "h":
    print("hours")
```

I don't know how to do this, I'm just guessing, could someone please help me? Thanks.

Comment: `if xtime.rstrip()[-1] == "m":`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem of your code is that what you're doing is adding a "m" if the string `xtime` is not null.

You should use `str.endswith` Python built-in function:

```
xtime = (input("Enter time (add: m for mins, or h for hrs): "))

if xtime.endswith('m'):
    print("mins")
elif xtime.endswith('h'):
    print("hours")
```

Answer (score -2):

You mean something like that:

```
user_entry = input("Enter time (add: m for mins, or h for hrs): ")

if user_entry == "m":
    print("mins")
elif user_entry == "h":
    print("hours")
else:
    print("Wrong entry, try again!")
```

Or:

```
user_entry = input("Enter time (add: m for mins, or h for hrs): ")

if user_entry.startswith("m"):
    print("mins")
elif user_entry.startswith("h"):
    print("hours")
else:
    print("Wrong entry, try again!")
```

Last edit:

```
user_entry = input("Enter time (add: m for mins, or h for hrs): ")

if user_entry.endswith("m"):
    print("mins")
elif user_entry.endswith("h"):
    print("hours")
else:
    print("Wrong entry, try again!")
```

Comment: No, they said "if the user inputs a **number** with 'm' (or 'h') *after*", so `==` is wrong.

Comment: Your second example is also wrong because they said the letter goes **after** and yet you have `startswith` and not `endswith`

Comment: I did edit. Now you can type in "m15" for example. You can you 'endwith' instad 'startwith'

Comment: end**s**with you mean...